# Can't access original array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a problem with my foreach loop. My foreach loop basically looks like this:

```
echo $values[0];
echo $values[1];

foreach ($values as $key => $value)
{
    echo $values[0];
    echo $values[1];
}
```

$values[0] should be "new york city" and $values[1] should be "new york". The problem is that in the foreach loop, both echos give the same value, whereas outside the loop they give the different (correct) values.

How do I access the original array ($values) normally inside of the foreach loop?

EDIT: I don't want to access the value $value. I want to be able to access any index of $values regardless of which iteration my foreach loop is on. I hope I am making sense.

Also, obviously I have alot more going on in this foreach loop, it was just meant as an example. The purpose of the foreach loop is not to print out these values.

Basically what the actual foreach loop I am using does is that it iterate through an array, and when it finds a certain value in that array, it iterates through the whole array again (inside the foreach loop). So basically I want a foreach loop inside a foreach loop, both for the same array, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should only use echo $value; in foreach loop.

Comment: You are not using the foreach loop. You would get the same effect if you called echo $values[0]; echo $values[1]; twice in a row. Maybe you wanted to write echo $value?

Comment: The code should work fine if it is intended.

Comment: Look, I don't want to access the value $value. If the foreach loop is on iteration 0, then $value will be $values[0]. I want to be able to access $values[1] when the foreach loop is only on iteration 0. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $val instead of $values[$i];

```
// Code goes here

foreach ($values as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Do not use foreach loop construct instead use for loop.